# plugin/preset files are not allowed to export objects only functions

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx, babeljs, react-dom

I am trying a simple JSX code to call from my html page. But when I try to compile the JSX code using Babel using command "browserify -t [ babelify --presets [ react ] ] src/App.js -o build.js" it throws error:

'Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions. In F:\Work Backup\simplereact\react-tutorial\node_modules\babel-preset-react\lib\index.js while parsing file: F:\Work Backup\simplereact\react-tutorial\src\App.js'

Please help!
index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.6/react.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.6/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel- core/5.8.23      /browser.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="src/app.js" type="text/babel"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';

var App = React.createClass({
render: function() {
return <div>Something something Dark Side</div>;
}
});

ReactDOM.render(
<App />,
document.getElementById('app')
);
export default App;
```

Package.json

```
{  
"name": "react-tutorial",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.4.4",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
"babelify": "^10.0.0",
"react": "^16.8.6",
"react-dom": "^16.8.6",
"react-scripts": "3.0.1"
},
"scripts": {
"start": "react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test",
"eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
"eslintConfig": {
"extends": "react-app"
},
"browserslist": {
"production": [
  ">0.2%",
  "not dead",
  "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "development": [
  "last 1 chrome version",
  "last 1 firefox version",
  "last 1 safari version"
  ]
  }
  }
```

Comment: You did not import react-dom import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

Comment: Still the same here persist. I have added react dom import but same error.

Comment: Try changing "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1", to "@babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1"

Comment: still same issue.

Answer (score 0):

According to reactjs.org, if you are not using ES6.

```
var createReactClass = require('create-react-class'); //create function like so.
var App = createReactClass({                     
  render: function() {
    return <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>;
  }
});
```

Comment: Please look at the command I am using to compile It might give you some better idea. Because still the problem persist.

Comment: Have you thought of using create-react-app? Just make sure that you install node, and then at command line type npx create-react-app appname. This will set up a basic react project for you.